# ng-click firing when selecting text or dragging

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

When using ng-click on a div:

```
<div ng-click="doSomething()">bla bla</div>
```

ng-click fires even if the user only selects or drags the div. How do I prevent that, while still enabling text selection?

Comment: dunno, try ng-click = "doSomething() ;  $event.preventDefault()" ?

Comment: Don't think so...
I'm trying to prevent the ng-click from firing at the first place...

Comment: What is that you are trying to achieve? Why do you have ng-click if you want to prevent it from firing?

Comment: I want it to fire on click, not on a mouse down + long mouse move + mouse up.

Comment: I need an answer to this too.  In my case, when the user pans (mousedown, drag, mouseup), we will handle that outside of angular.  It seems to me that ng-click should have a distance threshold such that if the mousedown location and the mouseup location are farther apart than the threshold, then it should not trigger the ng-click.

Answer (score 2):

In requiring something similar, where the usual text selection behavior is required on an element which should otherwise respond to `ngClick`, I wrote the following directive, which may be of use:

```
.directive('selectableText', function($window, $timeout) {
  var i = 0;      
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    priority:  1,
    compile: function (tElem, tAttrs) {
      var fn = '$$clickOnNoSelect' + i++,
          _ngClick = tAttrs.ngClick;

      tAttrs.ngClick = fn + '($event)';

      return function(scope) {
        var lastAnchorOffset, lastFocusOffset, timer;

        scope[fn] = function(event) {
          var selection    = $window.getSelection(),
              anchorOffset = selection.anchorOffset,
              focusOffset  = selection.focusOffset;

          if(focusOffset - anchorOffset !== 0) {
            if(!(lastAnchorOffset === anchorOffset && lastFocusOffset === focusOffset)) {
              lastAnchorOffset = anchorOffset;
              lastFocusOffset  = focusOffset;
              if(timer) {
                $timeout.cancel(timer);
                timer = null;
              }
              return;
            }
          }
          lastAnchorOffset = null;
          lastFocusOffset  = null;

          // delay invoking click so as to watch for user double-clicking 
          // to select words
          timer = $timeout(function() {
            scope.$eval(_ngClick, {$event: event});  
            timer = null;
          }, 250);
        };
      };
    }
  };
});
```

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/kkfXfiLvGXqNYs3N6fTz?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

I had to deal with this, too, and came up with something much simpler. Basically you store the x-position on mousedown and then compare new x-position on mouseup:

```
ng-mousedown="setCurrentPos($event)"
ng-mouseup="doStuff($event)"
```

Function setCurrentPos():

```
var setCurrentPos = function($event) {
  $scope.currentPos = $event.offsetX;
}
```

Function doStuff():

```
var doStuff = function ($event) {
  if ($event.offsetX == $scope.currentPos) {
    // Only do stuff here, when mouse was NOT dragged
  } else {
    // Do other stuff, which includes mouse dragging
  }
}
```